# Database structure to store company- branch - employee

Tags: mysql, database-design

I want to store this information in a database:

```
Company
   |
   |-- Dept 1--,
   |            \->Employee 1
   |             |->Employee 2
   |
   |-- Dept 2--,
   |            \->Employee 3
   |
   |-> Employee 4
   \-> Employee 5
```

I've already got this far: I need a employee table and the department and company items are just the same so they should be in the same table...

```
employee // id | information...
branch  //  id | information....
```

Each employee should be linked to a branch. And each branch can be connected to another branch...

```
employeeBranch // employee.id | branch.id | enum(current, historical)
branchBranch   // branch.id   | branch.id
```

This makes it possible to have multiple levels of branches...

But I'm doubting if this is *The* way to do it..

Comment: Can each branch only belong to one other branch?  Can employee's only belong to one branch?

Comment: Each branch is unique and can only belong to one other branch. An employee can belong to multiple branches. For instance when some has two jobs :) Or when somebody switched jobs i want to store that also (with the enum(current, historical)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If employees can only belong to one branch and branches can only be a child to one branch then you might consider adding a column to represent this information instead of whole new tables:

```
employee // id | branchId | information
branch   // id | parentBranchId | information
```

If you have many to many relationships for employee/branch and branch/branch then I think your original structure is fine.

Answer (score 3):

No, they should not be in the same table at all.

I see three tables: Employee, Company, and Department.

An Employee can belong only to one Company, assuming that you're modeling current employment only.  (One job at a time - no moonlighting.)   A Company can have one or more Employees, so Employee has  foreign key to Company.

A Company can have many Departments, but a Department can only belong to one Company.  So Department will have a foreign key to Company.

Modeling branches is only slightly trickier.  If one Department is a sub to another, I'd give Department a foreign key to itself.   The top level Department will have a null foreign key to other Departments, since it's the top level.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is smilier to what you said make each side has his own table with his information. Then make a relational table.

```
table `branches`

Branch ID           Branch Name         Branch Location
---------------------------------------------------------------
    2                   sd                  west
    1                   no name             east

table `employee`

employee ID         employee name           employee birth
---------------------------------------------------------------
    1                   name                    2/2/1975

table `employee_branches`

employee ID     Branch ID
--------------------------
    1               2
    1               1
```